# URL to provision Microsoft New Employee Onboarding sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, provisioning

I am reading this article @ [provision-neo-hub](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/provision-neo-hub) on how to provision NEO hub sites, but when i click on this link :-

[image]

I will be redirected to a page to provision the "MICROSOFT 365 LEARNING PATHWAYS" and not the NEO sites.. any advice please?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should be addressed in the respective Docs GitHub Issues.

Comment: @TrevorSeward did not get your point..

Comment: You should be reporting this on the associated GitHub repo where that page resides for a correction.

Comment: @TrevorSeward ok but meanwhile what is the url for creating new NEO sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The New Employee Onboarding (NEO) sites can be provisioned from here:

[NEW EMPLOYEE PRE-ONBOARDING SITE](https://lookbook.microsoft.com/details/8fefcc9a-7ca4-457f-bd10-acee3ae63b63)

[NEW EMPLOYEE CORPORATE ONBOARDING SITE](https://lookbook.microsoft.com/details/388a159f-475b-4557-9088-c9073a26c576)

[NEW EMPLOYEE DEPARTMENTAL ONBOARDING SITE](https://lookbook.microsoft.com/details/99d3b7ea-6ca0-430e-96bc-922d4d2de2ab)